# Custom field in checkout with proper server-side validation

Tags: checkout, javascript, validation

I've been trying to get this to work for a while now, and i've found out it's pretty easy to bypass now.

I've added my custom validation in `js/prototype/validation.js` and in the checkout step. However, when you inspect the element (with ex. Chrome) and remove the `validate-morgen` and `required-entry` classes, the input field will validate as `true`, which it isn't. Is there another way to make this that this field is being validated properly on the server-side?

`Validation.js`:

```
['validate-morgen', 'Voer een juiste morgen-bezorgen code in. Heeft u geen code? Gelieve telefonisch contact op te nemen.', function(v) {
    if (v != "gmos") {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
 }]
```

HTML input field:

```
<input id="morgen-bezorg-code" class="input-text validate-morgen"
    placeholder="Morgen-bezorgen code" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you submit the form to a controller action.
You can get the values submitted with `$this->getRequest()->getPost()`.
You can check if your field is filled in.
If it's not, redirect back with a message saying the field is mandatory.